# Trying to search through array of strings for a pattern the user inputs - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, indexing

```
var p = ["array of words", "i really hate the sun", "i'm TIred"]

function findword(contents,pattern){
    var answer;
    var idx;
    var counter = 0;
    var pat_lc = pattern.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i <= contents.length-1; i++){
        var str_lc = contents[i].toLowerCase();
        idx = str_lc.indexOf(pat_lc)
        if (idx >= 0){
            answer = i
        }
        else{
            answer = "-1"
       }
    }
    alert(answer)
}
findword(p,"words")
```

I'm trying to find the index of the array for a certain word, in an array of strings, however it only works for certain words in the array above. For example, on the last line of the code, when I chose to search for "words" it returns the value of "answer" and "idx" -1 when it should be 0 and 9 respectively. However, when I search for "tired", the value of "answer" is 2 and "idx" is 4 (which is correct). Why do some words work and others return the value of -1?

Comment: Why aren't you using a native funtion like `array.filter`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop as soon as you find a solution.

Your program only stops when it iterated over the whole array. But what if the answer what not in the last element ? Then `answer` will contain `-1`.

You can init `answer` at `-1` and continue your `for loop` as long as `i` is less than `content.length` and `answer` is equal to `-1` : http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dbVcN8JkKP

Comment: what happens if more than one match? Alerts wont help

Comment: @charlietfl The asker didn't give much specification about what is the correct answer. The answer following mine will give all matches. Oh, and its yours =)

Comment: Thanks for this, I totally understand what's going on now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified working version that will find all matches

```
var p = ["array of words", "i really hate the sun", "i'm TIred"]

function findword(contents,pattern){
    var matches=[];
    var idx;
    var pat_lc = pattern.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i <= contents.length-1; i++){
        var str_lc = contents[i].toLowerCase();
        idx = str_lc.indexOf(pat_lc)
        if (idx >= 0){
            matches.push({ idx: i, position: idx})
        }
    }
    return matches
}
```

Several problems

answer and idx get overwritten ever pass of the `for` loop. So regardless if a match was found...only last pass is returned. I saved the results into separate array that gets returned. Code you provided didn't do anything with `idx`.

Can test output for length to see if matches exist...no matches will return empty array with no length

Come to think of it...not sure what output you want

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Km8/8/)</kbd>