# A function that will search an array for letters and return the position in which those letters are

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, search

I've created a function that will search for individual letters from a string regardless of case and order. Here is what it looks like.

```
function match(string, pattern) {

    string = string.toLowerCase();
    pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
    var patternarray = pattern.split("");
    for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        if (patternarray[i] >= "a" && patternarray[i] <= "z") {
            if (string.indexOf(patternarray[i]) == -1) return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Now I want to do a similar thing except this time I will be searching an array, and instead of returning true/false I would like to return a new array containing the places in which the string pops up.

For example, if my variable contents were ["Oranges","Apples","Bananas"] and my search was "n", the function would return [0,2]. I am a beginner with JavaScript so thorough explanation would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I did something very simlar yesterday [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758896/trying-to-search-through-array-of-strings-for-a-pattern-the-user-inputs-javasc/19759015#19759015). Can take a lok and see if it helps you  . difference was they wanted word match, you would need to loop over each letter in word still

Comment: Still searching for an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function matchArray(array, pattern) {
    var i,
        len = array.length,
        result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (match(array[i], pattern)) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscorejs has a function that should take care of this for you.  Just take a look at the filter function.  It has the ability to return a new array with items that passed a truth test.

```
var aArray = _.filter(['asdf','ddd','afsf'], function(item){
  return (item.indexOf('a') !== -1);
}
```